# drawString method doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, drawstring

I have a `JPanel` object of which I'm using it as a canvas to draw rectangular shapes and call `updateString(String c, int x, int)` method to draw a `String c` whenever I call that method in my main.

I also have local variable called `private Graphics page;` on the top of my code. Here's `updateString()` method:

```
public void updateString(String c, int ind1, int ind2)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < Math.pow(DIMENSION, 2); i++ )
        if( grid[i].contains(new Point(ind1, ind2)))
        {
            page.drawString( c, (int) grid[i].getCenterX(), (int) grid[i].getCenterY());
            repaint();
            return;
        }
}
```

**grid[]** is my `Rectangle` objects' array to store the data of the `Rectangle` objects and I actually draw them inside my `paintComponent()` method.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    page = g;
    for( int i = 0; i < Math.pow(DIMENSION, 2); i++ )
    {
        g.drawRect(grid[i].x, grid[i].y, grid[i].width, grid[i].height);
    }
}
```

the point that I couldn't understand is why whenever I call the `updateString()` method, it just doesn't update and put the String in the middle of the rectangle that I initially drew?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very very wrong:

```
page = g;
```

You don't want to save the Graphics object to a field since this object is not long-lasting and this will lead to graphics failures, or NPE's or worse.

Instead either

- Do your drawing directly in your paintComponent method. This can be done by say creating an `List<String>` and storing your Strings to this List, then iterating through the List inside of paintComponent, drawing each line.
- Or draw in a BufferedImage, which is then drawn in the paintComponent method.
- Or put your text in some text component such as a JLabel or JTextArea.

Comment: Aha so It just terminates itself when the method is over. But is there any way to do that drawing inside another method?

Comment: @VerumInfiniti: Why not just put a JLabel in the middle and set its text?

Comment: Because my assignment was telling me so, anyway, I will do it in your way. I have considered before it, however, couldn't be sure because I thought that there must be a way to do this easy drawString thing.

Comment: @VerumInfiniti: Please edit your question and show *all* requirements, especially those that pertain to your problem. A few images of what you're trying to create might help as well as more detail on the problem itself.